# Finding the maximal number of lists that form certain rules?

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory

I have the following example:

```
data={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
NN=Length[data]/3;
subdata=Subsets[data, {3}];
```

I want to know all the possibility for the following rules:

***pick up `NN=3` terms from the `subdata`:***

```
select1={{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}; 
select2={{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 7}, {6, 8, 9}};
select3={{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 8}, {6, 7, 9}}; 
select4={{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 7}, {5, 8, 9}};
```

***Condition1:*** every list such as `select2` forms one permutation such as `data` and no repeated terms in all the selectlists (`select1`, `select2`, `select3`, `select4`).

***Condition2:*** Every term in the whole selectlists can only be used for one time. That means randomly pick `NN=3` terms from selectlists (`select1`, `select2`, `select3`, `select4`), except the lists itself I should not have any permutations. Please see the following example which doesn't fufill:

```
select1={{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}; 
select2={{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 7}, {6, 8, 9}};
select3={{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 8}, {6, 7, 9}}; 
select4={{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 7}, {5, 8, 9}};
```

I can chose three terms from select3, select4 and select2 such that `{{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 7}, {6, 8, 9}}` form one permutation again. So `select4={{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 7}, {5, 8, 9}}` should be changed to something like `select4={{1, 2, 7}, {3, 4, 9}, {5, 6, 8}}`where there is no possible way to form one permutation except the lists itself.

```
select1={{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}; 
select2={{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 7}, {6, 8, 9}};
select3={{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 8}, {6, 7, 9}}; 
select4={{1, 2, 7}, {3, 4, 9}, {5, 6, 8}};
```

I want to know the maximal number forming selectN (N=?) where all the lists selectN fulfill ***Condition1*** and ***Condition2***

> I know the following case:
>
> ```
> data={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
> NN=Length[data]/3;
> subdata=Subsets[data, {3}];
> ```
>
> I can get the maximal number selectN (N=10) by counting manually which fufill ***Condition1*** and ***Condition2***.
>
> ```
>   selects={{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}},
>            {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 6}},
>            {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 6}},
>            {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}},
>            {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}},
>            {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}},
>            {{1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}},
>            {{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6}},
>            {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}},
>            {{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}}
> ```

But when the data gets larger, it's difficult to count without programming. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand condition 2: what does "addition case" mean? And what does "give any above condition 1" mean?. As for condition 1: Is it correct that `select5 = {{1, 2, 9}, {1, 2, 8}, {5, 8, 9}}` fulfills condition 1? (Since the total is 45)

Comment: ha, sorry. select5 is not fufill because there are repeated number in select5 (what I mean I think should be one Permutation)

Comment: I think I understand now: Condition 2 means that it is not allowed that I can find a new list fulfilling condition 1 by combining subsets from several different lists - is that correct?

Comment: Assuming the above interpretation of condition 2 is correct, do the 3 subsets have to be from 3 different sets? What I mean is, would `select1 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}; select2 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,7},{6,8,9}}` fulfill condition 2? (Since I can select `{1,2,3}` from `select1` and `{4,5,7}`,`{6,8,9}` from `select2`)

Comment: yes, you are right that "Condition 2 means that it is not allowed that I can find a new list fulfilling condition 1 by combining subsets from several different lists".

Comment: `select1` and `select2` are not allowed because of the repeated term {1,2,3}, because I only want to use every term one time. Sorry for unclear statement. Thank you for pointing out! @LukasLang

Comment: Because of condition 2 it is invalid to have 4 selections like `{{1, 2, 3}, x, x, x}, {x, {4, 5, 6}, x, x}, {x, x, {7, 8, 9}, x}, {x, x, x, {10, 11, 12}}`, but what about `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, x, x}, {x, x, {7, 8, 9}, x}, {x, x, x, {10, 11, 12}}`, i.e. does invalidness follow from condition 2 if you have to take more than 1 subset from the same selection to form a permutation?

Comment: Yes, I also want to include this cases into account but I think it's more complicated (I don't want any random chose form any permutation except itself). So I asked the easy cases for the first time. It will be cool to know the other cases that arbitrary decomposition of the sets. Do you know any literatures about this? set-packing??? Thank you!@Coolwater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 9; r = 3;
data = Range[n];
subsets = Subsets[data, {r}];
```

The following constructs all possible selections. By construction the first part of condition 1 holds already:

```
selects = Nest[Catenate[Table[With[{remain = Complement[data, Sequence @@ i]}, Append[i, #] & /@
           ArrayPad[Subsets[Rest[remain], {r - 1}], {0, {1, 0}}, First[remain]]], {i, #}]] &, {{}}, n/r];
sz = Length[selects]
```

> 280

The conditions can be expressed as linear programming constraints:

```
(* sz 0/1-variables are used to indicate whether each selection included or not *)
c = ConstantArray[-1., sz]; (* Minimize the negative sum of variables to include as many as possible *)
lu = ConstantArray[{0, 1}, sz];

(* Without loss of generality we can let {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}} be included *)
lu[[1]] = {1, 1};

(* Second part of condition 1 *)
m1 = SparseArray[Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[Thread[{First[#2], #}] -> 1.] &, #]] &[
          Quotient[Lookup[PositionIndex[Catenate[selects]], subsets], n/r, 1 - n/r]]
b1 = ConstantArray[{1., -1}, Length[m1]];

(* Condition 2 *)
m2 = SparseArray[Mod[Total[SparseArray[Thread[Tuples[#, 2] -> 1.], {sz, sz}] & /@
     Partition[m1["NonzeroPositions"][[All, 2]], sz n/r/Binomial[n, r]]], n/r]]
b2 = ConstantArray[{n/r - 1., -1}, Length[m2]];

res = LinearProgramming[c, Join[m1, m2], Join[b1, b2], lu, Integers];
```

`res` happens to contain 13 ones, and the specific solution found is:

```
Pick[selects, res, 1] // Column

{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
{{1, 2, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 5, 7}}
{{1, 2, 9}, {3, 5, 6}, {4, 7, 8}}
{{1, 3, 4}, {2, 7, 9}, {5, 6, 8}}
{{1, 3, 7}, {2, 4, 6}, {5, 8, 9}}
{{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 8}, {6, 7, 9}}
{{1, 4, 7}, {2, 6, 9}, {3, 5, 8}}
{{1, 4, 9}, {2, 6, 8}, {3, 5, 7}}
{{1, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 7}, {3, 8, 9}}
{{1, 5, 9}, {2, 4, 8}, {3, 6, 7}}
{{1, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 5}, {4, 8, 9}}
{{1, 6, 8}, {2, 5, 7}, {3, 4, 9}}
{{1, 7, 8}, {2, 5, 9}, {3, 4, 6}}
```

Comment: thank you very much! The way of linear programming constraints is very nice, thank you very much!